# Вычисление медиан при построении k-d деревьев

Tags: дерево

Не понимаю принцип вычисления медиан. Разбираю одну задачу, имею следуюший набор данных: (3; 4); (6; 1); (6; 6); (9; 7); (11; 2); (13; 6); (15; 1).

Из этого необходимо построить k-d дерево. Я строю правильно, но у меня не все медианы сходятся с ответом. Вот правильный ответ на скриншоте:

[image: k-d дерево]

В чём моя проблема:
Считаю медиану 1: суммирую все значения Х, делю на 7. Получаю точно так же 9.
Считаню медиану 2: суммирую Y от (3; 4); (6; 1); (6; 6) и делю на 3. (1+6+4)/3 = 3.66.
Считаю медиану 3: у меня выходит 4
итд.
Т.е. очевидно что в решении считали медиану, делили элементы, а потом смещали медиану в сторону минимального из правой части.  Почему? Разве не обычная медиана должна использоваться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы путаете медиану и среднее значение.

Медиана - такое значение в наборе, что существует поровну элементов меньше его и больше его. Если набор отсортировать, то медиана будет стоять на среднем месте - иметь индекс `n/2`
*(для нечётного числа это место однозначно определено, для чётного один из средней пары считается медианой)*

Например, для набора `1,1,3,4,5,6,29` медианой будет 4, а среднее значение - 7.

После первого разделения у вас остаются `(3; 4); (6; 1); (6; 6);` с набором Y `1,4,6` медиана 4, и `(9; 7); (11; 2); (13; 6); (15; 1)` с набором Y `1,2,6,7` и медиана 6 как элемент с индексом 2 в сортированном порядке.

P.S. Для нахождения медиан полная сортировка не нужна, есть более быстрые методы (Quickselect)